# Check user existence on SharePoint

Tags: client-object-model

I deleted a user in Users and groups management of Office 365. But his information is still in Site Collection's All users.

How can I check if a user was deleted or not? Using Client Object Model.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to check the user existence. You can check following options:

```
var targetSite = new Uri("siteurl");
            var login = "username";
            var password = "password";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
            {


                clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                User spuser = web.EnsureUser("test user"); // This will give exception if user does not exist.

  // otherwise you can user collection and check if user exists of not.
                UserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
                List userinfos = web.SiteUserInfoList;
                clientContext.Load(users);
                clientContext.Load(spuser);
                clientContext.Load(userinfos);


                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (User user in users)
                {
                    if (user.LoginName == "")
                    { }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: if user is already in Site Collection All users, `EnsureUser` will still return SPUser object properly.

Comment: If the user exists but is not in the site collection yet, EnsureUser will add the user to the hidden userinfolist. Depending on your use case you might not want that, so keep it in mind. Use the profile service to check for existence otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online contains [Get-SPOUser cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161389%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to return the SharePoint Online user or security group accounts that match a given search criteria.

The similar CSOM example to determine whether user exist in a site collection:

```
public static bool ExistsSPOUser(Tenant tenant, string siteUrl,string loginName)
{
    var ctx = tenant.Context;
    var loginResult = tenant.EncodeClaim(loginName);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var encLoginName = loginResult.Value;

    var rootWeb = tenant.GetSiteByUrl(siteUrl).RootWeb;
    var siteUsers = rootWeb.SiteUsers;
    var usersResult = ctx.LoadQuery(siteUsers.Include(u => u.LoginName).Where(u => u.LoginName == encLoginName));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return usersResult.Any();
}
```

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(tenantUrl))
{

     ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
     var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
     if (!ExistsSPOUser(tenant,"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/", "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("User not found");   
     }
}
```

Comment: I think siteUrl shoud be contoso**-admin** or it will result in `Current site is not a tenant administration site.` error. But in my case, site to check isn't root site like this, my URL is kind of https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST/TEST and I'm facing `not a tenant administration site` problem. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not exactly, siteUrl parameter is the actual site Url against which user have to be verified, but tenantUrl parameter corresponds to Tenant Url (https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/ )

Comment: I've tested the specified code and it works for me

Comment: I got this error `The site https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx is not properly formed.` at the `ExecuteQuery` to get `usersResult`.

Comment: @VadimGremyachev
I'm trying to achieve a slightly different approach, I need to check if a specific user (not current user) is currently logged in into a specific sharepoint online root site, is that possible using only the user login email and the site url?

Answer (score 0):

You can tried to implement the following which retrieve profile data then you can check if the user still exist or not from output created.

```
#Create People Manager object to retrieve profile data
$Output = "D:\Output.csv"
$Headings = "Name","Email","OneDrive URL","Phone","Job Title","Department"
$Headings -join "," | Out-File -Encoding default -FilePath $Output

$PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
    $Context.Load($UserProfile)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
        $UPP = $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties
        $Properties = $UserProfile.DisplayName,$UserProfile.Email,$UserProfile.PersonalUrl, $UPP.WorkPhone,$UPP.'SPS-JobTitle',$UPP.Department
        $Properties -join "," | Out-File -Encoding default -Append -FilePath $Output
        }  
    }
```

The original post:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2014/02/27/office365-retrieve-user-profiles-using-csom.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but is it available in COM?

Comment: i have added another answer using COM. Hope any helps

Answer (score 0):

Using COM approach, i believe you can do something like this. Again you might need to tweak to suit your requirements.

```
var user;
var visitorsGroup;
var userCollection;
function getGroups() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var groupCollection = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_siteGroups();

    visitorsGroup = groupCollection.getById(7);//GroupID

    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    userCollection = visitorsGroup.get_users();
    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.load(visitorsGroup);
    clientContext.load(userCollection);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    for (var index = 0; index < userCollection.get_count(); index++) {
        if (userCollection.itemAt(index).get_loginName() === user.get_loginName()) {
          alert("User present in this group");
            return;
        }
    }
alert("User notpresent in this group");
return ;
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
    alert("User notpresent in this group");
return ;   
}
```

link:http://aviralchawda.blogspot.com.au/